# Error in my P5.play Editor - Exchange Error: you can only add sprites to a group

Tags: javascript, editor, p5.js

I'm doing a game where the user has to code using p5.play, so, I did an online editor as a first step, but, I'm having problems when I run the code:

--> When I write the code and run in the first time, everything works fine.
--> If I run the code for a second or more time (in the case to correct something), the code shows a lot of errors and finally appears: uncaught exception: Error: you can only add sprites to a group

I thought the problem was because I wasn't using a localhost server, but it wasn't it.
I think the problem is in the part of the preview frame, I need some way to delete the previous result in order to appear the new code, but I don't know how to make it.

The entire code is this link:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jRFmUKngpjwn6J2VFNqvkc3HuxoEmeAV

Comment: Hello @Paulo and welcome on stackoverflow. Could you please provide more information, such as: a minimal working example, the error messages, etc...

Comment: @BertrandGazanion here's the images when I run in the first time and when I run after this: [1.ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPi5B.png) [2.WHEN WORK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qo3vX.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, I create a button with this function:

```js
function refreshPreview(){
        var refresh = document.getElementById('preview');
        refresh.src = refresh.src;
        refresh.src = '';
      }
```

So, with it, my iframe screen makes the same as press F5.